# Discrepancy in Video Data From Activity Reports

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I trying to send this request to get the activity data:

```
YouTube.Activities.List activitiesListByIdRequest = youtubeService.activities().list(Collections.singletonList("contentDetails"));
activitiesListByIdRequest.setChannelId("xxx","yyy");
activitiesListByIdRequest.setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(50));
```

from this response, we get the list of the video id, we send the list to this request:

```
YouTube.Videos.List vidoesListByIdRequest = youtubeService.videos().list(Collections.singletonList("snippet,contentDetails,statistics"));
vidoesListByIdRequest.setId(videosListPerPage);
vidoesListByIdRequest.setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(50));
```

related to this response we should get only these channels("xxx","yyy") under the snippet.channelId.

but I get these channels and more channels differently.

the question: did this is the correct behavior? if yes why?

if not how can we resolve this issue?

expecting to get these channels("xxx","yyy") under the snippet.channelId.

but we get these channels and more channels differently.

Comment: any update related to this ticket?

Comment: any update  related to this ticket?